# Classic asp migration to windows 2008 RC

Tags: asp-classic

I am very new to asp classic application. The below code snippet is from a **asp classic application** which we are going to **migrate** to **Windows Server 2008RC**.

```
1.Set objConfig_Constantsinc = Server.CreateObject("Notion.Configuration")
2.Dim account
3.account = objConfig_Constantsinc.GetConfig("SQLAccount")
```

As per my understanding in **line number 1** we are **creating an instance of a COM class**. Now in **line number 3** using this instance we are trying to get some config data "SQLAccount" .
Here is my doubt. In classic ASP application where are we storing these type of configuration strings(For eg: "SQLAccount"). Is there any concept of global configuration file. Kindly guide me.

Comment: I think you should look in webconfig.ini. btw, are you planning on a pure port (keeping ASP.NET traditional) or a full rewrite (e.g. to ASP.NET MVC) ?

Comment: Thanks Mike. Here the requirement is like, we need to port the existing application which is running in Windows 2000 has to be ported as it is in to Windows server 2008 RC. It is in its very early stage of porting can you please tell me the probable challenges that I may face.

Comment: I think it should be no problem, just stick to the newest version of .NET. Since you're not migrating to new MVC everything should be as before. Still haven't a chance to play with 2008, sorry.

Comment: Mike, as you said I searched for .ini files in the solution folder. But I couldn't find any file having any string constants.

Comment: by "migrating" you do not mean rewriting do you? so you just put the classic asp application on a new server with windows 2008?

Comment: @BigMike classic asp is NOT ASP.NET. what do you mean with "ASP.NET traditional"?

Comment: @ulluoink I guess I've misunderstand the scenario :(

Comment: as the com class is reading the config value with its method GetConfig() you should have a look at this method to find out where these values are stored.

Comment: Thanks ulluoink. Migrating means just puting classic asp in to new server(2008).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments & by yourself, the Notion.Configuration item is some kind of com object, if you're porting this to the new server you dont really have a problem (assuming you port the underlying storage mechanism, **i.e. the com object could be storing the vars anywhere (Eg: sql, registry, files)**

If for some reason you want to do away with the com object for storing configuration data (i.e. your question regarding the existence of a global configuration file) - there is a mechanism for doing this in Classic ASP.

Specifically, the global.asa file, commonly, the common.asa file is placed in the root of your site and exposes application variables that can be read from any asp file within your application.

More Details: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525316(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525316%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Declaring application level globals is easy:

Example from a global.asa:

```
<script language="VBScript" runat="Server">
Sub Application_OnStart
    Application("SQLAccount") = "whatver"
End Sub
```

Example in any other asp page:

```
response.write Application("SQLAccount")
```

I would remind you though, that declaring unnecessary global vars is counterproductive & you should carefully choose what to expose at a global level to avoid confusion / duplicate items in memory.